# Angular 6 pass data to component on router menu click

Tags: angular, routerlink

I have a navmenu component as under:

```
     <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'></span> Configuration<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Options</li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['config']" [queryParams]="{optionFilter: 'LOB' }">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></span> Line of Business
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['config']" [queryParams]="{optionFilter: 'RG' }">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></span> Report Groups
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

There are dropdown menus under Configuration. All menus lead to the same component 'config'. However, based on the routerLink selected I need to write logic. How can I pass the param 'Line of Business', or 'Report Group' to the config component and retrieve in ngOnInit?

Comment: Take a look over here in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass that in query parameters:

```
<a [routerLink]="['config'] [queryParams]="{ someProperty: 'ReportGroup' }">
```

Inject `ActivatedRoute` in the component's constructor, and subscribe `queryParams` or `queryParamsMap`.

Or

2. You can make it two separate routes, pointing to the same component. Again, inject `ActivatedRoute`, but subscribe route params instead of query params.

Answer (score 0):

Passed queryparams as suggested by mbojko, and retrieved in the component as under:

```
//import router in component
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

//constructor:
    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }
 ngOnInit() {
        this._route
            .queryParams
            .subscribe(params => {
                this.FilterOption = params['optionFilter'];
                console.log('menu click', params['optionFilter']);
            });
}
```